# Core Location plist not working (Xcode 9.4/iOS 11.4)

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

Trying to do a base Core Location test in Xcode 9.4...

I have clearly missed something.

Have put in three entries into info.plist to allow Core Location to run:

- Privacy - Location Always Usage Description
- Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
- Privacy - Location when in Use Usage Description

The questions don't pop up on my iPhone 7 or the simulator when you run the App and there is no setting for the App under Settings/App Listings...

Do I need all three entries (paranoia) and if not which one(s) can I delete?
Any ideas what I've missed?

[image]

Comment: You are required to include the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription keys in your app's Info.plist file. (If your app supports iOS 10 and earlier, the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription key is also required.) If those keys are not present, authorization requests fail immediately.

Comment: The plist where you have added is the UITest plist. Please add the keys into the project plist. as mentioned in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From screenshot I am getting that you have inserted strings to another plist file which is in UITests folder.

Insert that (`NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`, `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription`) strings to **YOURPROJECT/YOURPROJECT/Info.plist**

Also please select the simulated location while you are running your project in simulator.

Hope it will work.

Comment: Absolutely correct - never occurred to me that there would be two info.plist files. Only entered "Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description" and it worked first time. Many thanks.

Comment: @EdwardHasted Happy to help you :)